# Deleting an entity with a List<String> causes "Referential integrity constraint violation"

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, h2

I have an Entity ("Saunoja") with a List of Strings. When trying to delete a Saunoja from H2-console, the following error occurs:

```
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKIL684UE3YHG0N80RMHVIFQTA0: PUBLIC.SAUNOJA_ROLES FOREIGN KEY(SAUNOJA_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SAUNOJA(ID) (1)"; SQL statement: DELETE FROM "PUBLIC"."SAUNOJA" WHERE "ID"=? [23503-200]
```

I had the same problem with another property of the Saunoja entity, but it got fixed with an answer to a similar question asked here before.
Because this property is a List composing of antohter Entity, and a @OneToMany relationship is in question, the solution was to add a @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE), but in this instance it is not working, because it is not an actual @OneToMany relationship.

atm my Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Saunoja extends AbstractPersistable<Long> implements Comparable<Saunoja> {

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<String> roles;

    private LocalDateTime created;

    private Long profilepictureId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "author")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private List<Photo> photos;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Saunoja other) {

        return username.compareToIgnoreCase(other.username);
    }

}
```

A separate table is made for persisting the roles. The table is called SAUNOJA_ROLES. Probably something to do with annotations of the List of Strings..?

Allready tried it like this (and all sorts of combinations):

```
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn
    private List<String> roles;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that annotating an object property as an ElementCollection makes it hard or impossible to delete the Entity in question as straight  forward as usually: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5528.

And ElementCollection is the way to go with a List of Strings though.

Thus, my solution to the problem was to programmatically erase the List before the deletion of the entity. There seemed to be no way to cascade a deletion to the list.. Anyhow, this fixed my problem for now:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('GOD')")
    public void deleteSaunoja(String username) {

        Saunoja saunoja = saunojaRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (saunoja != null) {
                        
            saunoja.getRoles().clear();

            saunojaRepository.save(saunoja);

            saunojaRepository.delete(saunoja);
            
            deletedSaunojaRepository.save(new DeletedSaunoja(username, LocalDateTime.now()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: As you found out, there is an open issue for this. It will eventually be fixed, but if this is important to you right now, you can try to provide a fix yourself or engage someone to do this for you like e.g. Red Hat or a consultant. FWIW you could use Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views for this purpose which offers a method `entityViewManager#remove(Object)` that handles removing in a more efficient way and also considers already loaded data properly: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage